# Как выделить шаблонность из функции?

Tags: c++, проектирование, шаблоны-с++, рефакторинг

Имеем - шаблонная функция, еще и рекурсивная, в которой много чего подтянуто из разных (заголовочных) файлов, а шаблонность только одна - запись найденного значения в итератор. Что-то примерно такое

```
template<typename Itor>
void terribleFunction(Itor it, type1 param1, type2 param2, ...)
{
    // Всякие дела
    for(....
    {
        // И еще дела

        // Первое использование it
        if(...) terribleFunctiom(it,p1,p2,...);
        // И еще...

        // Второе использование it
        if (...) *it++ = что-то;  

        // И еще...
    }
}
```

Примерно так. Хочется максимально спрятать весь код - в котором ничего шаблонного - или в библиотеку, или в отдельный файл - вобщем, как минимум постараться не плодить зависимости в заголовочном файле, выписывая в нем весь код, постараться максимально убрать его в какие-нибудь вспомогательные функции, что ли. Но что-то что ни придумываю - все через одно неприличное место...

Какой бы тут хитрый метод применить, намекните?...

Comment: @Abyx Пока да :) И еще - в рекурсивном вызове.

Comment: Именно в такие моменты не хватает класса `std::iterator<>` который играл бы ту же роль, что и `std::function<>`. `std::function<>` - это средство type erasure для функторов, а `std::iterator<>` был бы аналогичным средством type erasure для итераторов. Именно это пытается реализовать "на коленке" @yrHeTaTeJlb в своем ответе, но это можно было сделать элегантнее. (Да, я знаю, что `std::iterator<>` уже занято другой функциональностью.)

Comment: @Abyx Ой, простите - вы так намекали, а я не заметил... Конечно же, я описАлся - `*it++ = что-то`...

Comment: @Abyx Конечно, нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если единственное использование - это `X x = expr; *it++ = x;`, то эту операцию можно обернуть в `std::function<void(X)> f`, передавать не итератор а эту функцию, использовать как `f(x)`.

Либо можно передавать класс с виртуальными функциями.

Comment: Простите, я вчера уже был крепко задолбанным, не сообразил, о чем вы - конечно же, `*it++=value`. С утра, похоже, тоже не очень соображаю :) - я думал о таком варианте, но не очень понимаю, как конкретно это делать - ведь функция-то будет тоже шаблонной, нет? Мне просто нужно, чтоб эта функция могла работать с любым контейнером, а равно с выводом в файл - потому и решил сделать через итератор.

Comment: @Harry, `std::function` не нужно быть шаблонной, т.к. «что-то» у Вас имеет конкретный тип. Делаете как Abyx написал и лямбду туда передаёте. Не очень красиво, но работать будет.

Comment: @ixSci Т.е. итератор просто оказывается захваченным? Вы бы не могли привести какой-то минимальный пример кода (не на основе моего), потому что без этого какой-то ступор...

Comment: @Harry, что-то [такое](http://ideone.com/6LxNxY)

Comment: @ixSci Спасибо, так понятнее. никак не решу, какой же метод более прост. И - как я понимаю, в этом случае рекурсивно передается тот же объект `function`?

Comment: Сравнил оба варианта. Все же этот покороче :)

Answer (score 4):

По сути, все что вам нужно это полиморфное поведение вашего итератора. Сейчас вы достигаете полиморфизма за счет шаблонов. Можно достичь того же эффекта при помощи наследования и виртуальных методов.

Для начала объявим интерфейс итератора:

```
class IIterator{
public:
    virtual void next() = 0;
    virtual void setValue(int value) = 0;
    virtual int value() const = 0;
    virtual ~IIterator(){}
};
```

Думаю вы знаете тип значения, которое хотите писать в итератор. Для примера я взял `int`.

Теперь нам нужна конкретная реализация, причем для всех возможных итераторов. Да, снова шаблоны:

```
template<class It>
class Iterator : public IIterator{
    It _iterator;
public:
    explicit Iterator(const It &iterator):
        _iterator(iterator)
    {}
    void next(){
        ++_iterator;
    }
    void setValue(int value){
        *_iterator = value;
    }
    int value() const{
        return *_iterator;
    }
};
```

Теперь возьмем весь код из `void terribleFunction(Itor it)`, перенесем его в функцию `void terribleFunctionHelper(IIterator &it)`, и внесем некоторые изменения в использование итераторов:

```
void terribleFunctionHelper(IIterator &it){
    //...
    it.next();         //Раньше тут было ++it;
    it.setValue(42);   //Раньше тут было *it = 42;
    //...
}
```

Код `void terribleFunction(Itor it)` теперь станет таким:

```
template<typename It>
void terribleFunction(It it){
    Iterator<It> iterator(it);
    terribleFunctionHelper(iterator);
}
```

В результате этих нехитрых манипуляций, все зависимости оказались в нешаблонной `terribleFunctionHelper`. Можно смело переносить ее код в cpp файл.

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/2z4iv)

Comment: Простите, что снял "псису", но все же ваш вариант более трудоемкий...

Comment: @Harry, но более гибкий :) Хотя, конечно, если вам точно не понадобится ничего кроме `*it++` то лучше сделать проще

Comment: Я в растрепанных чувствах :( Не могу выбрать! Оба варианта хороши... Пришлось просто изойти :) из моей конкретной задачи и количества строк.